# Passing a function with arguments to a delegate expecting none

Tags: c#, events, parameters, delegates

I know in Python you can use `functools.partial` to pass a function object with some or all of the parameters already defined.

Is there a way to do this in C#? I would like to do the following:
`class1.MethodTakingAMethodParameter(3, "foo", class1.MethodToPass(param1, param2, param3));`

For a delegate like `delegate void Blah()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lambdas to give some parameters a value:

```
Action paramlessDelegate = ()=>MyFunc(value1,value2,value3)
```

Or if you want to only put a value into some params:

```
Action<int> oneParamDelegate = (remainingParam)=>MyFunc(value1, remainingParam, value3)
```

In your example:

```
class1.MethodTakingAMethodParameter(3, "foo", ()=>class1.MethodToPass(param1, param2, param3));
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's neat! I guess lambdas are something I need to look into more.